# Accessing and printing vector of vectors initialized with new

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, heap-memory

How can I access and print with "cout" an element of a vector that is stored inside another vector that has been initialised dinamically.

So, for example I have a vector and a vector of vectors created with "new"

```
vector<int> v1;
v1.push_back(1);
v1.push_back(2);
vector<vector<int> >* vV = new vector<vector<int> >();
vV->push_back(v1);
// way to access v1[0] from vV and way to cout << vV[0][0] (just an example)
```

I'm creating the vector of vectors with new because I need it to be very big, so I need to allocate it to the heap, as if I allocate on the stack it crashes.

Comment: Allocating with `new` isn't going to do any good. When you create a vector, all but a *tiny* bit of the data is allocated from the free store (i.e., using `new`) anyway.

Comment: A vector of zero ints takes up exactly the same space on the stack as a vector of 1 million vectors, each of 1 million ints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parentheses:

```
std::cout << (*vV)[0][0] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use indirection and `at()`;

```
  cout << vV->at(0)[0] << endl;
```

Comment: irrelephant's answer using the subscript operator is more efficient if the bounds checking of std::vector::at is not needed.

Comment: @Troy, And not using a pointer in the first place is even better :)